Image tag NgOptimizedImage not working when using ngSrc instead of src
I have the following img tag working perfectly, but my IDE tells me to move to ngSrc instead of src
<img alt="Konami" src="assets/imgs/konami.gif">

So I try to move to ngSrc but the gif isn't loaded anymore
<img alt="Konami" ngSrc="assets/imgs/konami.gif" height="280" width="498">

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Have you imported NgOptimizedImage directive as stated in the documentation?

As my img tag is in the index.html I try to add it to my app.module.ts but same issue. The weird thing is that my browser console is empty of any warning/error

Ah, that's the reason. index.html is an entry point for bootstrapping Angular app. You can't use any Angular directive, component (except bootstrap component). So if you want to use ngSrc, you need to move that <img> element in the components instead of in the index.html.
